# Registering channel uri with cloud service

Tags: azure, push-notification, wns

According to this video (between times 9:40 and 12:50)

https://youtu.be/GwoAjG_tgGQ?t=9m40s

The presenter explains how to get the channel uri in Step 1. and then Step 2 is how to register with the cloud service.  However I'm not clear about the scenario he depicts about associating the channel uri of a user with some context.

For example say the user want to receive notification alerts for specific news articles, well after sending the channel uri to the cloud service, how do you combine that with the context (i.e. the news articles that particular user wants to be notified on)?

I was thinking - can you send the channel URI to the cloud service along with settings - like this

```
{
 channelURI: uri,

 notificationSettings: {whatever setting options user entered in the app settings go hers - that the cloud service understands to deliver notification to this Uri}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> However I'm not clear about the scenario he depicts about associating the channel uri of a user with some context.

According to your description, I watched the video your provided for delivering notifications with WNS. Per my understanding, you need to store the channel URI with a single user in your cloud service back-end (e.g use [Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables) to store the record) and update the cloud server when the URI changes.

For a single user who subscribes the specific actions, you need to store the user subscribed actions with the channel URI of this user in your back-end storage, then when the subscribed actions of a user is triggered, you could invoke a HTTP request to the user's channel URI with the specific payload and authorization code to send a push notification.

Additionally, for a simple way you could leverage Notification Hubs as follows `Notifications.Instance.Hub.SendWindowsNativeNotificationAsync(toast, userTag)` to push notifications to the specific users. For more details, you could refer to this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification).